# How to reload page every 5 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am converting one layout to html; once I make the changes in code/html/css, every time I have to hit F5. Is there any simple javascript/jQuery solution for this? I.e. after I add the script, reload the whole page every 5 seconds (or some other specific time).

Answer (score 462, accepted):

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=http://www.yourdomain.com/yoursite.html">
```

If it has to be in the script use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) like:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.reload(1);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I think this is probably a better way of doing it than in javascript.

Comment: If the use case was that the page needed to refresh for visitors then I might agree, but for development purposes, having a block of code that you can drop into the page without having to update a URI each time is an advantage. Depending on JS isn't a problem when the developer is the entire target audience.

Comment: location.reload(1) will repeat a POST if the current page is the result of a POST. That might not be desirable, if you are looking to replicate the meta refresh in Javascript.

Comment: Reloading the current page doesn't require you to specify the page,  Just: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">`

Answer (score 179):

To reload the same page you don't need the 2nd argument. You can just use:

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />
```

This triggers a reload every 30 seconds.

Comment: It is [discouraged when used for redirect](https://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/reback). It is not deprecated. (And it comes in very handy when you want to refresh a page and are too lazy to learn ajax :)

Comment: This isn't working for me.  Tried adding this line to this codepen to no avail. https://codepen.io/css-support/pen/bspdK

Comment: @lololololol You have to add it in the "Stuff for <head>" setting in the HTML's Pen Settings area. It doesn't work if you put it in the actual script.

Answer (score 28):

For auto reload and clear cache after 3 second you can do it easily using javascript setInterval function. Here is simple code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    cache_clear()
  }, 3000);
});

function cache_clear() {
  window.location.reload(true);
  // window.location.reload(); use this if you do not remove cache
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Auto reload page and clear cache</p>
```

and you can also use meta for this

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5">
```

Comment: Page refresh <script> is working but can you explain how it is clearing the cache?? or it is jus refreshing the cache.. pls explain.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721704/window-location-reload-with-clear-cache, if you want to lean more then please google it

Answer (score 18):

```
setTimeout(function () { location.reload(1); }, 5000);
```

But as development tools go, you are probably better off with [a tab reloading extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-reloader/).

Answer (score 11):

There's an automatic refresh-on-change tool for IE.  It's called ReloadIt, and is available at http://reloadit.codeplex.com . Free.

You choose a URL that you'd like to auto-reload, and specify one or more directory paths to monitor for changes.  Press F12 to start monitoring.

[image]

After you set it, minimize it.  Then edit your content files. When you save any change, the page gets reloaded.  like this:

[image]

Simple. easy.

Comment: Nice tool for IE, and thanks for animated thing. How can I create the same?

Comment: @WasimShaikh - Record your screen to an animated GIF using [ScreenToGIF](https://www.screentogif.com/).

Answer (score 8):

Answer provided by @jAndy should work but in ***Firefox*** you may face problem, **window.location.reload(1)**; might not work, that's my personal experience.

So i would like to suggest:

```
setTimeout(function() { window.location=window.location;},5000);
```

This is tested and works fine.

Answer (score 3):

A decent alternative if you're using firefox is the [XRefresh plugin](http://xrefresh.binaryage.com/). It will reload your page everytime it detect the file has been modified. So rather than just refreshing every 5 seconds, it will just refresh when you hit save in your HTML editor.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively there's the application called [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/)...

Answer (score 3):

This will work on 5 sec.

*5000 milliseconds = 5 seconds*

**Use this with target `_self` or what ever you want and what ever page you want including itself:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function load()
{
setTimeout("window.open('http://YourPage.com', '_self');", 5000);
}
</script>
<body onload="load()">
```

**Or this with automatic self and no target code with what ever page you want, including itself:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function load()
{
setTimeout("location.href = 'http://YourPage.com';", 5000);
}
</script>
<body onload="load()">
```

**Or this if it is the same page to reload itself only and targeted tow hat ever you want:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function load()
{
setTimeout("window.open(self.location, '_self');", 5000);
}
</script>
<body onload="load()">
```

All 3 do similar things, just in different ways.

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing and testing in Firefox, there's a plug-in called "[ReloadEvery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/115)" is available, which allows you to reload the page at the specified intervals.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function reload() {
  document.location.reload();
}

setTimeout(reload, 5000);
```