# Javascript function to reload a page every X seconds?

Tags: javascript, html, syntax

A couple of questions:

- I've never really used JS listeners other than `onclick` and `onkey` events, so I wondered if someone could help me with what I need in order to reload the page every X seconds?
- Secondly, the page contains bare minimum, literally just one input box. Do I still need to include the html `head` and `body`?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787679/how-to-reload-page-every-5-second

Comment: are u refreshing ? or you want only to update the data?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You don't need Javascript for this simple function. Add in the page header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="300">
```

300 is the number of seconds in this example.

Comment: Nice! Js have tendency to stop working untill you reload page yourselt. Will test this.

Answer (score 33):

To reload the page after 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds) using JavaScript, add the following to the bottom of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function () { location.reload(true); }, 5000);
</script>
```

As Greg Hewgill notes, you can also accomplish this with the meta refresh tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5">
```

Strictly speaking, you do still need `<html>` and `<body>` tags.  Some browsers may render the page correctly without them, but your are safest to include them.

Comment: The java script option gives me an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: settimeout is not defined `

Comment: @Zapnologica: the second 't' in `setTimeout` is capitalized.

Comment: Very important that if you want it to refresh every X seconds, you will need to use the setInterval(function(){}, X); not setTimeout(), where the anonymous function in setInterval is run every X miliseconds

Answer (score 2):

use a timer: http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/
and usee ajax to reload if it is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

To your second question, ye you definitely do!!

Toy your first question check this out:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/autofresh.shtml

Or this to do it without javascript:

http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/a/aa080300a.htm

It does what you asked and is very easy to configure!