# Refresh page every 10 seconds in background

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, header, refresh

I am stuck on this scenario where I want a page to auto refresh every
10 seconds. I have used

```
header("refresh: 10;");
```

which does work when I access the URL through my browser, but i want
it to run in background. I have used Cron to access the url once and
then it should refresh the page every 10 seconds. But this doesn't
work.. can anyone please tell me the solution to this ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript function to reload a page every X seconds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992353/javascript-function-to-reload-a-page-every-x-seconds)

Answer (score 4):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; URL=http://www.domain.com/">
```

or just

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
```

or try this in a script

```
setTimeout(function(){
  window.location.reload(1);
}, 10000);
```

Comment: thanku ... will this work even if browser is closed ??

Comment: No it won't. Then I think you need to explain a little more what you are trying to achive

Comment: It would not. All of these solutions are only for when a user visits the page. If you want it to run automatically, you need a CRON-job, which can only be run every 1 minute.

Comment: What should be updated if the page is closed? I think what you need is to run a cron job instead. Can you please explain what you want to do?

Comment: i want to run my php code to fetch data from twitter api. Now i cannot keep the browser 24/7 to refresh it every 10 seconds. I want the process to run in background./ Although cronjob works great but it only allows me to run proccess every 1 minute... i need to run script every 10 seconds.

Comment: It's not possible refresh a page that's not open so then I think you need to look at something like [this](http://serverfault.com/a/246046) Another alternative is to set a infinite loop in php and use sleep()

Answer (score 0):

Try this code put it in head of html page

< meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" >