# Javascript to refresh a webpage at an exact time (milliseconds)

Tags: javascript

firstly i am very very very new at this and by no means competent, so please do reply to me as if im a 3 year old child!

I am trying to find a way to refresh a webpage at an exact time (milliseconds), as im trying get to the front of my golf club queue for booking!

I was using Imacros to spam the heck out of the refresh button and this works to some extent, then i started reading about timings and using java through the Inspect / Console in Chrome.... so...

Im looking for some code that i can use to refresh the page at a given time, shorter than a second, i can then trial when is the best time to actually start the process for best results.

if anyone can help me, that would be great

Nick

Comment: I've removed the Java tag from your question.  The inspect/console in Chrome lets you run Javascript, not Java.  They're two completely different languages (well, ALMOST completely different).  I don't think this question has anything to do with Java.  Please let me know if you think I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="300">`

[Javascript function to reload a page every X seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992353/javascript-function-to-reload-a-page-every-x-seconds)

I think it is close to this

Answer (score 0):

**Try this,**

```
setTimeout(reloadPage, 500);

function reloadPage() {
  location.reload(true);
}
```

Comment: thanks how do i set the time?

Comment: change the 500 to any value 1000 means 1 second

Comment: great, will it repeat? and can i set it to start at a specific time?