# How to automatically refresh ejs page

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh, ejs

Im new with ejs. As I was trying out an app. I want to refresh the page every 5 sec.

I got a code

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval("location.reload(true)", 5000);
        });   
</script>
```

But how to include jquery in ejs? How to embed this code in ejs page?

Comment: Please refer below URL:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787679/how-to-reload-page-every-5-second

Comment: Its not helping me. my current location is localhost:3000

Comment: it worked thanx. Post it as answer plz

Comment: will close the question :)  as duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

tags: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">.` That simple. The "5" is the number of seconds. If you want to increase the time to say 20 minutes, you simply put in "1200" and so on.