# node.js with EJS templating: How to update view programatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have a EJS template that's used to display several steps:

1. Display a button, that starts a process on the node.js backend
2. Display information what's happening. This step has a duration of 10s.
3. Display a textinput and button

Transitioning from step 1 to step 2 is easy: The button triggers a post request that returns the updated view with the new `step`-value. **I'm struggeling with the timed transition from step 2 to step 3**. I either

1. Need to update the HTML output to the client from the server
2. Implement a `setTimeout();` in the EJS template.

Second option is maybe easier, but I'm not able to get something like

```
<% if (step == 2) { %>
    <p>Step 2 is happening right now</p>
    <%
    setTimeout(function() {
        step = step + 2;
    }, 1000 )
    %>
<% } %>
```

to work. [This approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287189/how-to-automatically-refresh-ejs-page) is not working for me, since the 10s start after the button from step 1 pressed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the setTimeout call within the context of an EJS template is not going to work. That code is executed on the server so when it DOES execute, if at all frankly, the HTML would've already been sent to the client.

Comment: Thanks Joey, I ended up with `<script>
  setTimeout(function() {
   window.location = window.location.href;
  }, 1000);
  </script>` to trigger a new reload without POST data