# Django refresh data

Tags: python, django, page-refresh

I am relatively new to django and have no previous experience of web development.
One of my views reads data from a device trough python and shows them in html page.

How can I refresh the page every x seconds without external input? I am looking for something similar to a while loop in python programming.

Comment: Use JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload and [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787679/how-to-reload-page-every-5-second
The isn't Django specific btw.

Comment: thank for answering: fast and easy!