# Manage HTTP method types

Tags: java, http, servlets

How do you manage specific HTTP method types for Java? I think has to do with servlets. I tried searching online but I don't quite understand it.

I read something to do with extending to the genericServlet which allows implementation of HTTP requests. Then this allows me to utilize HTTP method types? I'm just really confused

Comment: Use a framework, like Spring MVC and then you can specify which methods are handled by which bits of code without writing boilerplate.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html

Comment: Don't hand-write servlets. Use Spring MVC or Jersey to handle all of that low-level detail for you.

Comment: You should use a framework like Spring or struts etc.

Comment: @chrylis this depends if OP is looking for a way to implement yet another web MVC framework. In that case, extending from `GenericServlet` is the way to do.

Comment: Thanks everyone, all your answers were really helpful and exactly what I needed :D. I could only pick 1 correct one unfortunately. But they were all really useful. Thanks!!

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza If he's not familiar enough not to need to ask about the servlet methods, then I'd still recommend not implementing a framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should extend `HttpServlet` and implement `doGet()`, `doPost()`, `doPut()` etc instead of `GenericServlet`.

Please read good tutorial on Servlets/JSP.

Look at [`HttpServlet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html).

Answer (score 2):

[`HttpServlet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.htm) class provides generic methods to accomplish this:

- `doGet` for GET requests
- `doPost` for POST requests
- `doPut` for PUT requests
- `doDelete` for DELETE requests

And that's all.

If you want to support other [HTTP methods](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html), like TRACE or CONNECT, then you should extend from [`GenericServlet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html) and do all this work manually by overriding [`GenericServlet#service`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#service%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) method. Take into account that this may involve several work. You could also forget about extending from one of these classes and do it all yourself by implementing [`Servlet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html) interface. Examples of these:

- [`DispatchServlet`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) from Spring MVC framework, which extends from `HttpServlet`.
- [`FacesServlet`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-api/2.2.8/javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet.java#FacesServlet) from [JavaServer Faces](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/) framework, which directly implements `Servlet` interface and do all the work by itself. It provides support for OPTIONS, HEAD, TRACE and CONNECT methods apart from the 4 methods described above.

If you're specifically looking about how to implement a RESTful API, then it would be better to use a framework that implements [JAX-RS](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/) like [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) or [RestEasy](http://resteasy.jboss.org/) or [Restlet](http://restlet.com/)

Comment: @Huko don't worry. Be cool and have a good day.

Comment: Can you please answer my question if you have any idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881013/control-c-application-from-java-web-application