# simple web browser with auto refresh by webkit python

Tags: python, webkit, gtk, raspberry-pi, reload

I'm trying to develop a simple digital signage system with raspberry-pi computer. What I'm actually trying to do is open a web page (which carrying information to be displayed) in full screen mode and refresh this page at certain interval of time. I came across some web view codes in python using "gtk" and "webkit" I managed to open a url in full screen mode, but I dont know how to use reload function as per my needs. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the two ways that are already described using a cron job (not an elegant way) or using javascript, it is also possible to schedule the reload in the python script.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib
from gi.repository import WebKit2

class  ReloadView:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Gtk.Window()
        window.connect('delete-event',Gtk.main_quit)

        self.view = WebKit2.WebView()
        self.view.load_uri('http://example.net')
        GLib.timeout_add_seconds(5, self.reload) #every 5 seconds

        window.add(self.view)
        window.fullscreen()
        window.show_all()

    def reload(self):
        self.view.reload()
        #self.view.reload_bypass_cache() for complete reload
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ReloadView()
    Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer and upvoting what is helpful to you. This way others can benefit from your experience.

Comment: sir I have a doubt about putting this pyton script on auto start. I've tried some methods but nothing worked. can you help me? the code you menotioned works fine when run mannually. but i want to run this script automatially when raspberry pi get turned on. what should i do?

Comment: Maybe [these instructions](http://embeddedday.com/projects/raspberry-pi/a-step-further/running-python-script-at-boot/) can help you. Otherwise, you should probably post this as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this resource that seems to have some valid solutions for your problem: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/6981/auto-refresh-for-midori

These scheduled actions are usually handled by cron jobs, but there is nothing preventing you from writing your own simple action scheduler.

edit: alternatively if you control the website itself, you could set the website itself to refresh with a certain interval. The ways to do this are described here: [How to reload page every 5 second?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787679/how-to-reload-page-every-5-second)

Comment: @PradeepSathyan: for sake of completeness I made a small update to my answer. Not sure if it is helpful in your case.

Comment: @peter That was my plan B. LOL! thank you once again. :)