# django continuous api data and saving into database

Tags: python, django, api

Suppose I am getting a list of user from an api in json format and I want to save it in my User model in django. Saving the user might not be a problem but I want that data continuously.

I am getting an api from a system which sends me the list of user who sent emails. These users go on increasing.

Now I am getting a list of users. I want to save these users in my database. But the questioning part is, suppose 10 user has sent messages I am getting list of 10 users from api then I will save it say like

```
usr = User()
usr.username = data["username"]
usr.save()
```

Now what when 1 more user sends the email. Now I will be receiving 11 user.

Here I want continuously add the updated user in my database. How to do this ?

I dont know if I have made it clear or not but need help on this

Comment: I am not sure if I understood the question but you can make the `username` field unique to prevent it from recorded into the table multiple times.

Comment: I dont want to make it unique I want username of same character can be saved. Consider username as name... But the thing is how can I save continuously

Comment: It's not clear what "continuously" means in this context. Do you mean that you need to save multiple users in a single request? Can you show an example of the JSON input you want to act on?

Comment: Lets say its not username its phone number. I want my database updated continuously when someone email.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is how to trigger the retrieving of the emails.

A very easy way to do this is to use a timed autoreload - you can do this easily in html. See this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787679/how-to-reload-page-every-5-second). Then your django view can check for new emails and respond with the new data.

Answer (score 0):

as per my understanding, you want to check for the new data entries periodically and save the new records into db. Right?

So for periodic tasks [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) is the best utility. 
once you get data periodically then get db data into list_db and API data into API_list. Now start comparing both the lists data and store the new one into db.

I hope this will help.