# Reloading the page for certain amount of times in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to reload a page for a specific amount of times, let us say I want to reload a page for 10 times once the dom is loaded?

Comment: .. Why?​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: This has already been answered.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787679/how-to-reload-page-every-5-second

Comment: Dayan you understood the question in a wrong way, I don't wanna reload the page every specified amount of time I want to reload it for number of times

Comment: Adding to what @Dayan link says (the JavaScript way, not using the header), if you want to reload the page just a certain amount of times, save a value in a cookie or in the localStorage and retrieve/update it before reloading the page with JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.onload=function(){
if(!window.localStorage.getItem("count"))
    window.localStorage.setItem("count",0);
else
   {
    var count= window.localStorage.getItem("count");
       if(count<10)                                              
       {
          window.localStorage.setItem("count",count+1);location.reload();
       }
   }
  };
```

Comment: The first `if`, shouldn't it be `if (!window.localStorage.getItem("count"))`? (if the count item does not exist, set it)