# How to reload page.php on certain time, ex: at 07.45. Not duration time, ex: every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, php

I have problem. I want to reload/refresh page.php in specific time, ex at 07.45 not every duration time, ex every 5 minutes. I'm not finding yet until now. Maybe in php or javascript or other solutions. Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787679/how-to-reload-page-every-5-second

Answer (score 1):

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10" />
```

Or

```html
setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.reload(1);
}, 10000);
```

If you want to refresh page on certain time, get time using date('H:i') function of PHP. Refresh page inside if condition, keep calling this function after some time duration using setTimeout. Whenever condition get satisfied with provided time in condition, page will refresh.