# How to auto refresh/redirect a view in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

Is there a way to auto redirect (or refresh) a template (or better: it's underlying **view**) after the passage of a *set amount of time* in Django? E.g. via using [Redirect view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview) or something similar? An example would be nice.

Essentially I need to approximate `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60;url here">`, but in Django. Of course, I know exactly how the meta refresh tag in HTML works - but this question doesn't pertain to that (or to using JS to achieve the same effect). That tag has its own problems, e.g. it doesn't work in Opera Mini (a critical browser for my audience).

Comment: Django is server side so it isn't anything you can do on that end, this needs to be done client side

Comment: [Better duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2787679/1324033)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can achieve that using Javascript, example:

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    location.href = "http://myurl.com";
}, 5000); // refresh/redirect after 5 seconds.
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ali. I'd consider this as "Plan B", since doing it natively inside Django remains my top priority for reasons beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I don't believe you can refresh a page that is sent to the client using your backend; once a page is sent to the client you have no control over it.

Comment: @HassanBaig yes you can, just add them inside `<script>`. If you want the server to determine what the redirect url is, pass it to your template and then `location.href = "{{ redirect_url }}";`

Comment: To confirm, This should go in the <head> of the template, right?

Comment: @HassanBaig it works wherever you put it.

Comment: @Ali what exacty should I pass to template in views.py? I mean the url name as a string? ` return render(request, context={ 'redirect_url': 'some_url_name_as_string')` is it right?