# Javascript which refreshes page after time runs out

Tags: php

So I was wondering how I can the the current time and subtract it from another, and lets say there is 20 min left, then if the time runs out the page has to be refreshed, keeping the POST data too.

```php
if($TestJob['Timestamp']-$currentTime is less or equal than 0 sec){
  //refresh page (keep POST data / or just make a new post using only one value like the id "32")
}
```

Comment: with windows reload you will lose POST data, either use ajax or form submit

Comment: Can a JS run in the background and automatically refresh the page after a certain time? and also attach a unique?

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2787691/2996989) you can using settimeout

Comment: you can get around it by covert post data to get