# Data Array in HTML Script is not updating in flask when dynamic data is sent

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-restful, flask-socketio

I am using python Flask to build an application. When i give **static data** to array [] ran, azi it gets updated in the HTML Script console log, but when i **dynamically** update this array the data of the array in Javascript of HTML is not updated in the console.

initial case when static data is given **(in this case the data is updated successfully in HTML Script and console)**

```
 azi=[0,30,45,60,90]
 ran=[200,500,800,1000,1500]
 dopp=[]    
 @app.route('/dashboard.html')
 def dashboard():  
    return render_template('dashboard.html',azi=azi,ran=ran,dopp=dopp)
```

**Supporting HTML Script Code**

```
<script>
 var Range = {{ran}};
 var Angle = {{azi}};
 console.log("Range Array = {{ran}}");
 console.log("Azimuth Array = {{azi}}");
</script>
```

Code snippet,  when i try to **update the array dynamically**, **but it doesn't get updated in HTML Script** Console. (azi, ran and dopp are global variables)
i am getting the data through a ethernet cable, **the value of azi,ran and dopp array [] is getting updated in the python code (app.py), but the same dynamic array value when passed to HTML is not getting updated in the script.**
[This the snip of google chrome console where i am getting a blank array, but the array is dynamically updating in python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXlwy.png)

```
   #azi,ran and dopp are global variables
        azi=[]
        ran=[]
        dopp=[]
                
  def ethernet():    
    print("Initialising....\n")
    time.sleep(1)
    s = socket.socket()
    shost = socket.gethostname()
    ip = socket.gethostbyname(shost)
    host = input(str("Enter server address: "))
    name = input(str("\nEnter your Command: "))
    port = 10
    print("\nTrying to connect to ", host, "(", port, ")\n")
    time.sleep(1)
    s.connect((host, port))
    print("Connected...\n")

    start_time = time.time()
    while(1):
        ran=[]
        azi=[]
        dopp=[]        
        if(time.time() - start_time >= 0.5):
            start_time = time.time()
            s.send(name.encode())
            s_name = s.recv(1024)
            s_name = s_name.decode()
            print(s_name, "Received\n")
            char = "x"
            indices = [i.start() for i in re.finditer(char, s_name)]
            a=s_name            
            NumOfCent = (int(a[0 : indices[0]]))
            MessageType = (int(a[indices[0] + 1 : indices[1]]))
            DwellNo = (int(a[indices[1] + 1 : indices[2]]))
            
            for i in range(2, len(indices) - 3, 3):
                Range = (int(a[indices[i] + 1 : indices[i + 1]]))
                Range /= 8.0
                ran.append(Range)         
                print(Range)
                print(ran)    
          
                Azimuth = (int(a[indices[i + 1] + 1 : indices[i + 2]]))
                Azimuth /= 8.0
                azi.append(Azimuth)
                print(Azimuth)

                Doppler = (int(a[indices[i + 2] + 1 : indices[i + 3]]))
                print(Doppler)
                print('')
                dopp.append(Doppler)
                x = np.multiply(Range,np.sin(Azimuth*3.14/180))
                y = np.multiply(Range,np.cos(Azimuth*3.14/180))
```

I am new to python Flask,  Thanks For Your Help :)

Comment: Can you provide the full function that is not working? Also, what is the value of `indices`?

Comment: @nonDucor I am getting data from ethernet cable, i have also updated the indices part. Dynamically array value is getting updated in python code , so i dont think there is an error in the function where i am updating the data of array. The main issue is i am not able to pass dynamic value of array to HTML. Tho, the data is passed when i give static value to array in the same code.

Comment: Your second code snippet is not inside any function. It should be inside the `dashboard` function. Can you provide the complete function, otherwise we do not have enough information to help you.

Comment: @nonDucor for your reference i have given the ethernet function, but still i want to mention that ethernet function in working perfectly fine, the global variables, azi, ran and dopp are getting dynamically updated constantly in the python file (app.py). But when i try to use these array in HTML Script (Code snippet 2), then i get an empty array in the javascript (verifed in google chrome console)

Comment: In Flask, your HTML response will only be re-generated when the `dashboard` function is executed. If it is not being executed, the HTML will not be updated.

Comment: @nonDucor I want the array to be updated every second, so how can i do that? As far as I know dashboard function will be executed when i visit './dashboard' then how can i execute dashboard function every second if i want the data to be updated every second?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787679/how-to-reload-page-every-5-seconds) answer your question?

Comment: @nonDucor I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787679/how-to-reload-page-every-5-seconds), now the page is refreshing every 5 second but the array is still not updating. So my issue is still unsolved.

Comment: Are you sure these variables are global? Nowhere in the code you provided they are declared as `global`. Particularly, they are not global in your definition of `ethernet()`. You may want to search how globals work in Python and how to declare them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def ethernet():    
    print("Initialising....\n")
    time.sleep(1)
    s = socket.socket()
    shost = socket.gethostname()
    ip = socket.gethostbyname(shost)
    host = input(str("Enter server address: "))
    name = input(str("\nEnter your Command: "))
    port = 10
    print("\nTrying to connect to ", host, "(", port, ")\n")
    time.sleep(1)
    s.connect((host, port))
    print("Connected...\n")
    ran=[]
    azi=[]
    dopp=[] 
    start_time = time.time()
    while(1):
        if(time.time() - start_time >= 0.5):
            start_time = time.time()
            s.send(name.encode())
            s_name = s.recv(1024)
            s_name = s_name.decode()
            print(s_name, "Received\n")
            char = "x"
            indices = [i.start() for i in re.finditer(char, s_name)]
            a=s_name            
            NumOfCent = (int(a[0 : indices[0]]))
            MessageType = (int(a[indices[0] + 1 : indices[1]]))
            DwellNo = (int(a[indices[1] + 1 : indices[2]]))
            
            for i in range(2, len(indices) - 3, 3):
                Range = (int(a[indices[i] + 1 : indices[i + 1]]))
                Range /= 8.0
                ran.append(Range)         
                print(Range)
                print(ran)    
          
                Azimuth = (int(a[indices[i + 1] + 1 : indices[i + 2]]))
                Azimuth /= 8.0
                azi.append(Azimuth)
                print(Azimuth)

                Doppler = (int(a[indices[i + 2] + 1 : indices[i + 3]]))
                print(Doppler)
                print('')
                dopp.append(Doppler)
                x = np.multiply(Range,np.sin(Azimuth*3.14/180))
                y = np.multiply(Range,np.cos(Azimuth*3.14/180))
    
    return ran,azi,dopp


@app.route('/dashboard.html')
def dashboard():
    ran,azi,dopp = ethernet()
    return render_template('dashboard.html',azi=azi,ran=ran,dopp=dopp)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).